# Custom created_at attribute on a pivot Model

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

**Situation**: I have a model (let's call it `Pivot`) who is declared as follows:

```
class Pivot extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    .....
}
```

It has 5 fields: `id`, `notification_id`, `device_id`, `created_at`, `read_at`.

This model is used as the pivot table between `Notification` and `Device`:

```
// Notification.php
public function devices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Device::class)
        ->withPivot(['id','created_at','notification_id','device_id', 'read_at']); 
}

public function pivots() {
    return $this->hasMany(Pivot::class);
}
```

And i did the same inside the Device class.

My MySQL has a timezone (`Europe\Rome`) different then UTC and i can't change it because it is already used by different projects.

**PROBLEM**: How to setup the `created_at` field to work properly?

I tried to use default timestamps, it works BUT it will also add the `updated_at` column and I can't have it (it would add too many redundancy).

So i set `public $timestamps = false;` and i created the field in the database like that:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

The problem of this one is that, as said earlier, MySQL has a wrong timezone (`Europe\Rome`), so when I read data from this table the `created_at` value is shifted by 2 hours from the original. This is a problem when i also set the `read_at` property, because it creates situations where the notification is read before the creation.

The last idea i had was to set the `created_at` inside a creating event. I followed [this laracast guide](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/10) but, apparently, if the data is inserted as a pivot table from a `sync` method, events are not called (they didn't worked for me).

Do you have other ideas? of course there are some ugly hacks that could work (like iterating on the created `Pivot` and set them manually), but i would like to use a better solution.

EDIT: the solution proposed by @Maraboc worked perfectly. I set the timezone property of MySQL config array in `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ],
```

Comment: What about changing the time zone just in the current laravel project ? in the `config/database.php` `'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',....,'timezone'  => '+00:00']` !

Comment: I will give it a try!

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) to set the timestamp when you are creating the model. You can set the field and timezone together.

```
class Pivot extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        static::creating(function($model) {
            $model->create_at = Carbon::now('Europe\Rome');
        });

        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `parent::boot()` or else no traits will get booted on the model.